# Access certain values in data set

Tags: angular

I have the following data set and I am trying to access certain values within it.

```
{
    "id": "0f0126f5-aed3-49bb-97dd-7ad2d00b67a4",
    "retirementData": "{\"benefits\":[{\"availableBenefitOptions\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-01-21T22:00:00Z\",\"hasPensionBackedHomeLoan\":false,\"retirementAge\":65,\"schemeName\":\"BenCorp Alexander Forbes Retirement Fund Pension Base Fund\",\"schemeNo\":\"199\"},\"contribution\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-01-21T22:00:00Z\",\"employerContributions\":[5.0,10.0],\"hasEmployerContribution\":true,\"hasMemberContribution\":true,\"hasVoluntaryContribution\":true,\"memberContributions\":[5.0,10.0],\"voluntaryContributions\":[5.0,10.0]},\"investmentStrategy\":{\"defaultOptionId\":0.0,\"hasClarity\":null,\"hasSinglePortfolio\":true,\"isComprehensive\":null,\"isLifestage\":null,\"lifestage\":null,\"portfolioOptionId\":null,\"defaultLabelName\":null},\"qualifyingMembers\":{\"hasContract\":false,\"hasDisabilityClaims\":false,\"isFullTime\":true,\"isOverRetirementAge\":false,\"isPartTime\":false,\"isPermanent\":false,\"isUnderRetirementAge\":false}}],\"fundSalaryOptions\":[5.0,6.0]}",
    "locations": [{
        "id": 78
    }]
}
```

I am specifically trying to access the value of `'defaultOptionId'` but I get an undefined error when doing `console.log(this.exploreService.corpSettings.retirementData.benefits);`

I could access values up to `this.exploreService.corpSettings.retirementData` but nothing beyond that.

I had to stringify the response to show it here as I'd only see [Object, Object] in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What need to do is,
As retirementData is in string format, you need to convert it in object first
like,

```
JSON.parse(this.exploreService.corpSettings.retirementData).benefits
```

Working example

```js
var a = {
    "id": "0f0126f5-aed3-49bb-97dd-7ad2d00b67a4",
    "retirementData": "{\"benefits\":[{\"availableBenefitOptions\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-01-21T22:00:00Z\",\"hasPensionBackedHomeLoan\":false,\"retirementAge\":65,\"schemeName\":\"BenCorp Alexander Forbes Retirement Fund Pension Base Fund\",\"schemeNo\":\"199\"},\"contribution\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-01-21T22:00:00Z\",\"employerContributions\":[5.0,10.0],\"hasEmployerContribution\":true,\"hasMemberContribution\":true,\"hasVoluntaryContribution\":true,\"memberContributions\":[5.0,10.0],\"voluntaryContributions\":[5.0,10.0]},\"investmentStrategy\":{\"defaultOptionId\":0.0,\"hasClarity\":null,\"hasSinglePortfolio\":true,\"isComprehensive\":null,\"isLifestage\":null,\"lifestage\":null,\"portfolioOptionId\":null,\"defaultLabelName\":null},\"qualifyingMembers\":{\"hasContract\":false,\"hasDisabilityClaims\":false,\"isFullTime\":true,\"isOverRetirementAge\":false,\"isPartTime\":false,\"isPermanent\":false,\"isUnderRetirementAge\":false}}],\"fundSalaryOptions\":[5.0,6.0]}",
    "locations": [{
        "id": 78
    }]
}

console.log(JSON.parse(a.retirementData).benefits)
```

Comment: Oh man, I was over complicating so much, thank for your help sir

Comment: @skydev always a pleasure :)